# How can i use accordion to show collections documents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb, meteor

My requirement:
1. Get the data from the mongo collection and display into accordion
2. Set the active ID of the selected html accordion tag same as that of the document from collection.
3. Get the dropdown transition when we click in any one accordion entry in UI.
**sample.html**

```
     {{#each listjobs}}
        <button class="accordion">{{platform}}</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul class="panel_elements">
                  <li><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" /></li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="abc" value="abc" />{{abc}}</li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="def" value="def" />{{def}}</li>
                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="ghi" value="ghi" />{{ghi}}</li>
                  <li><input type="submit" name="trigger" value="Trigger" /></li>
                  <li id="status">SUCCESS / FAIL</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
```

**sample.css**

```
    button.accordion {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
        background-color: #ccc;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    button.accordion:after {
        content: '\002B';
        color: #777;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    button.accordion.active:after {
        content: "\2212";
    }

    div.panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
    ul.panel_elements{
      list-style-type:none;
    }
    ul.panel_elements li{
      display:inline-block;

    }
```

**sample.js**

```
Template.trigger.events({
    'click .accordion':function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
    },

});
```

The list is displayed by fetching entry mongo collections, but when i click on the job in UI the accordion drop-down doesn't comes up!!.
Can anyone please help me to solve this? or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why not just reuse this? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate

Comment: Worked like charm..Tq@blueren

Comment: Added the same as a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've reused what's already available [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate):

**Template:**

```
{{#each listjobs}}
<button class="accordion">{{platform}}</button>
<div class="panel">
   <ul class="panel_elements">
              <li><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" /></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="abc" value="abc" />{{abc}}</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="def" value="def" />{{def}}</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="ghi" value="ghi" />{{ghi}}</li>
              <li><input type="submit" name="trigger" value="Trigger" /></li>
              <li id="status">SUCCESS / FAIL</li>
        </ul>
{{/each}}
```

**CSS:**

```
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```